# How do I apply a Macro on multiple Outlook folders from ThisOutlookSession module

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, macros

Using information from this site, I have been able to create a macro to sort messages into a "sender name" subfolder, when I move the message into the parent.
for instance:

1. I receive a message in my inbox.
2. I move the message into the "follow-up" folder
3. If there is no subfolder named sender name it is created

   3a. The message is immediately moved into follow-up/sender name

The code below performs these steps perfectly.  What I need to do now is apply the code to other folders.  At the moment, my code sits in the "ThisOutlookSession" module, because I want it to work automatically.

My question is: How do I apply the macro to multiple subfolders of the inbox?
ie:

inbox  - not applied here

```
  follow-up  - applied here
  team       - applied here
  vendors    - applied here
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace

  ' set object reference to default Inbox
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Follow-up").Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
' fires when new item added to default Inbox
' (per Application_Startup)

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim targetFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim senderName As String

  ' don't do anything for non-Mailitems
  If TypeName(item) <> "MailItem" Then GoTo ProgramExit

  Set Msg = item

  ' move received email to target folder based on sender name
  senderName = Msg.senderName

  If CheckForFolder(senderName) = False Then  ' Folder doesn't exist
    Set targetFolder = CreateSubFolder(senderName)
  Else
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set targetFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("follow-up").Folders(senderName)
  End If

  Msg.Move targetFolder

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub

Function CheckForFolder(strFolder As String) As Boolean
' looks for subfolder of specified folder, returns TRUE if folder exists.
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim FolderToCheck As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olInbox = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("follow-up")

' try to set an object reference to specified folder
On Error Resume Next
Set FolderToCheck = olInbox.Folders(strFolder)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not FolderToCheck Is Nothing Then
  CheckForFolder = True
End If

ExitProc:
Set FolderToCheck = Nothing
Set olInbox = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Function

Function CreateSubFolder(strFolder As String) As Outlook.MAPIFolder
' assumes folder doesn't exist, so only call if calling sub knows that
' the folder doesn't exist; returns a folder object to calling sub
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olInbox = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Follow-up")

Set CreateSubFolder = olInbox.Folders.Add(strFolder)

ExitProc:
Set olInbox = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this and wonders, I was able to figure it out on my own.  I'm still pretty new at this, and didn't realize I could change the "Items" tag to define what I was looking at and then set the new variable each to point to their own folder.  Once I did that, I was able to add a sub for each folder and I was off.

```
Private WithEvents Corporate As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents Subsidiary As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents ServDsk As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents Vendors As Outlook.Items


Public Sub Application_Startup()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace

  ' set object reference to default Inbox
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set DefFol = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  Set Corporate = DefFol.Folders("Corporate Teammates").Items
  Set Subsidiary = DefFol.Folders("Subsidiary").Items
  Set ServDsk = DefFol.Folders("Service Desk").Items
  Set Vendors = DefFol.Folders("Vendors").Items

End Sub


Private Sub Corporate_ItemAdd(ByVal up As Object)


' fires when new item added to default Inbox
' (per Application_Startup)

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim targetFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim senderName As String
  Dim dirstr As String
  Dim strDomain As String


  ' don't do anything for non-Mailitems
  If TypeName(up) <> "MailItem" Then GoTo ProgramExit

  Set Msg = up

  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

  ' move received email to target folder based on sender name
  senderName = Msg.senderName
  dirstr = "Corporate Teammates"



  If CheckForFolder(senderName, dirstr) = False Then ' Folder doesn't exist
    Set targetFolder = CreateSubFolder(senderName, dirstr)
  Else
   ' Set olApp = Outlook.Application
   ' Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set targetFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(dirstr).Folders(senderName)
  End If

  Msg.UnRead = False
  Msg.Move targetFolder

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & dirstr
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub

Private Sub Subsidiary_ItemAdd(ByVal up As Object)


' fires when new item added to default Inbox
' (per Application_Startup)

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim targetFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim senderName As String
  Dim dirstr As String


  ' don't do anything for non-Mailitems
  If TypeName(up) <> "MailItem" Then GoTo ProgramExit

  Set Msg = up

  ' move received email to target folder based on sender name
  senderName = Msg.senderName
  dirstr = "Subsidiary"

  If CheckForFolder(senderName, dirstr) = False Then ' Folder doesn't exist
    Set targetFolder = CreateSubFolder(senderName, dirstr)
  Else
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set targetFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(dirstr).Folders(senderName)
  End If

  Msg.UnRead = False
  Msg.Move targetFolder

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & dirstr
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub

Private Sub ServDsk_ItemAdd(ByVal up As Object)


' fires when new item added to default Inbox
' (per Application_Startup)

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim targetFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim folderName As String
  Dim dirstr As String


  ' don't do anything for non-Mailitems
  If TypeName(up) <> "MailItem" Then GoTo ProgramExit


  ' move received email to target folder based on sender name
  dirstr = "Service Desk"

' checks the subject to decide how to handle the sorting
Select Case True
   Case InStr(Msg.Subject, "Demand") > 0
    folderName = "Demands"
   Case InStr(Msg.Subject, "Demand") = 1
    folderName = "Demands"
   Case InStr(Msg.Subject, "Incident") > 0
    folderName = "Tickets"
   Case InStr(Msg.Subject, "Problem") > 0
    folderName = "Tickets"
   Case InStr(Msg.Subject, "Opened") > 0
    folderName = "Tickets"
   Case InStr(Msg.Subject, "task") > 0
    folderName = "Tasks"
   Case InStr(Msg.Subject, "Status") > 0
    folderName = "Tickets"
   Case InStr(Msg.Subject, "TASK") > 0
    folderName = "Tasks"
   Case InStr(Msg.Subject, "Approval") > 0
    folderName = "OCH Approval requests"
   Case InStr(Msg.Subject, "Request") > 0
    folderName = "Requests"
   Case InStr(Msg.Subject, "Maintenance") > 0
    folderName = "Maintenance"
   Case InStr(Msg.Subject, "Alert") > 0
    folderName = "Alerts"
   Case InStr(Msg.Subject, "Notice") > 0
    folderName = "Alerts"
   Case InStr(Msg.Subject, "Reminder") > 0
    folderName = "Alerts"
End Select


  If CheckForFolder(folderName, dirstr) = False Then ' Folder doesn't exist
    Set targetFolder = CreateSubFolder(folderName, dirstr)
  Else
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set targetFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(dirstr).Folders(folderName)
  End If

  Msg.UnRead = False
  Msg.Move targetFolder

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & dirstr
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub

Private Sub Vendors_ItemAdd(ByVal up As Object)


' fires when new item added to default Inbox
' (per Application_Startup)

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim targetFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim senderName As String
  Dim dirstr As String
  Dim strDomain As String


  ' don't do anything for non-Mailitems
  If TypeName(up) <> "MailItem" Then GoTo ProgramExit

  Set Msg = up

' strips the domain name out of the sender address
  If InStr(1, Msg.SenderEmailAddress, "@") > 0 Then
         strDomain = Right(Msg.SenderEmailAddress, Len(Msg.SenderEmailAddress) - InStr(Msg.SenderEmailAddress, "@"))
  End If


If CheckForFolder(senderName, strDomain) = False Then ' Folder doesn't exist
    Set targetFolder = CreateSubFolder(senderName, strDomain)
  Else
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set targetFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Vendors").Folders(strDomain)
End if

  Msg.UnRead = False
  Msg.Move targetFolder

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & dirstr
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub





Function CheckForFolder(strFolder As String, dirstr As String) As Boolean
' looks for subfolder of specified folder, returns TRUE if folder exists.
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim FolderToCheck As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")


Set olInbox = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(dirstr)


' try to set an object reference to specified folder
On Error Resume Next
Set FolderToCheck = olInbox.Folders(strFolder)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not FolderToCheck Is Nothing Then
  CheckForFolder = True
End If

ExitProc:
Set FolderToCheck = Nothing
Set olInbox = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Function




Function CreateSubFolder(strFolder As String, dirstr As String) As Outlook.MAPIFolder
' assumes folder doesn't exist, so only call if calling sub knows that
' the folder doesn't exist; returns a folder object to calling sub
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set olInbox = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(dirstr)
Set CreateSubFolder = olInbox.Folders.Add(strFolder)


ExitProc:
Set olInbox = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Function
```